# Is it possible to retrieve the STUN server used once the RTCPeerConnection is connected

Tags: webrtc, stun, sdp

Not sure the title makes a lot of sense. To add some context, we are building a WebRTC infrastructure and to so do we have a few STUN servers up and and running.

We sometimes have users complaining of call taking too long to connect therefore we would like to get some analytics on the calls. Because we provide a list of STUN IPs (including some public STUN as backup), we would like to detect the STUN server that successfully initiated the call.

We have collected a bunch of information thanks to [RTCPeerConnection.getStats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats) but there is nothing related to the STUN itself. So for my questions:

- is there any JS API that allow us to retrieve the STUN used?
- is there any tool that I am not aware of that could do the job?
- do the SDP contains any information related to STUN?

Hope all of this is clear, thanks for your kind replies

Answer (score 1):

The statistics do contain a server url:
https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcicecandidatestats-url
However, that is not implemented and since STUN servers are not involved in the actual call that information is unlikely to be useful.

For TURN servers you can get the active candidate pair and the IP of any relay involved from getStats. See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/ for a sample that shows how to determine the active candidate pair.